# Internal Anchors in vb6 in webbrowser control

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, anchor

How can I make internal anchors work on WebBrowser control?

This is what I tried so far:

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 

  WebBrowser.Navigate "about:blank"
  DoEvents    

  WebBrowser.Document.Open
      WebBrowser.Document.Write "<html><head></head><body><a href=""#target"">link</a><a id=""target"" name=""target""><h1>target</h1></a></body></html>"
  WebBrowser.Document.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you describe how it is going wrong? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Click a link, re-loads about:blank instead of jumping to the bookmark

Comment: Sorry? --------

Comment: This happens when trying to display html without writing it to a file / launching a server. You generare an empty html doc by opening about:blank, then write your html there. If the html has an internal anchor it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using js to write the document allows internal links, but the html string must be javascript escaped.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim shtml As String

  WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "about:blank"
  DoEvents

  shtml = "<html><head></head><body><a href=""#target"">link</a><a id=""target"" name=""target""><h1>target</h1></a></body></html>"

  WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript "document.write(" & Chr(39) & shtml & Chr(39) & ")"

End Sub
```